# LinkedIn Profile With Respect To Past Employment

Tags: work-experience, united-states, linkedin, employment-gaps

I have been at my current company as a software engineer for the past three years.

However, after graduating from college and before starting my current job, I had three different jobs within a year.

- My first job was as an IT technician, but I left to pursue a programming job.
- My second job as an entry-level programmer ended unexpectedly (according to the owner, it was decided to bring in programmers with prior experience -- they did give me a positive recommendation).
- My third job was as a temp programmer, and I left to accept an offer for my current full-time position.

I have these three different jobs currently listed on my LinkedIn profile, but have been considering removing them. I have no reason to keep these jobs listed, but conversely, I have no reason to remove these listed jobs other than decreased relevance (I worked these positions for a short period of time, and I do not envision myself looking into being an IT technician anytime soon). Ideally, I'd have my current job and my education listed.

Would it be acceptable to not list these jobs and only list my current job? Why or why not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would include them because they're relevant to your current position and positions you want. They're how you got where you are. I've had numerous contacts from hiring managers (not just recruiters) based on what I have in my experience that I have listed.

The downside to not including them is it makes someone wonder either "is this is first work experience" or "why isn't he showing his history?" neither of which are positive responses.

Just remember that while LinkedIn is a good place to list your experience, it doesn't replace a resume, it complements it.

LinkedIn is all about networking and making contacts. Unless there's a compelling need not to, show off your entire **relevant** experience.  You don't have to put that summer you delivered pizza.

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons people have a LinkedIn profile.

1. is to find a job. They function as an approximation of a resume.
2. is to let past coworkers find you. This maintains a network that may in the future help you, or them , find a job.

Dropping past employers/jobs makes it harder for former co-workers to find you. If you have a common name and you only list your current job that  may make some people unlikely to invite you to join their network.

Only listing your current job decreases the number of search hits on your profile.

If you are comfortable with a smaller network and fewer search hits, go ahead and trim away.